# How to render multiple Markdown files on one page in Astro?

Tags: javascript, astrojs, static-site-generation

I want to render the contents of multiple `.md` files on a single page using Astro.

I have this file structure:

```
pages/
  items/
    item-1.md
    item-2.md
    item-3.md
    // etc
  index.astro
```

`item-1.md` looks like this:

```
---
title = 'Item 1'
---

Item 1 main text
```

And in `index.astro`:

```
---
const items = await Astro.glob([
    './items/*.md',
]);
---

<html lang="en">
    <body>
        {items.map((item) =>
            item.Content
        )}
    </body>
</html>
```

What I get as a result is:

```
[object Object][object Object][object Object]
```

Instead of the expected:

```
Item 1 main text
Item 2 main text
Item 3 main text
```

How can I make it so that the output HTML calculated from Markdown appears on the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`item.Content` is an Astro component, so in your `index.astro` file you will need to render it like this:

```
---
const items = await Astro.glob('./items/*.md');
---

<html lang="en">
    <body>
        {items.map((item) =>
            <item.Content />
        )}
    </body>
</html>
```

You could also destructure it in the map, but these are functionally equivalent:

```
        {items.map(({ Content }) =>
            <Content />
        )}
```

Comment: How do you can excerpt from the content rather than the whole thing?

Comment: @toxaq To do that, you’ll need to decide how the excerpt is generated. If you want to slice the first n characters, or first n paragraphs, you’ll need to grab the raw Markdown, chop it up based on that logic and then potentially either strip Markdown characters, or use a custom Markdown renderer to render it to HTML. It depends a lot on your use case, so I’d recommend asking a new SO question where you can provide details about your project and what you’re trying to do.

Comment: Hey @swithinbank, thanks for that. Worked it out in the end. The confusion arose because I was using the content collection which only returns a component, not the rendered text. There's a lot more raw stuff available with the glob method so basically had to double load the files in the end to not have to rewrite the whole blog from scratch.

Comment: Content collections should return a `body` property that is similar to the `rawContent()` you get in the glob version. Glad you’ve got it working!